# Simplified tensor formula

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, linear-transformations, tensor-products

A is a fourth-order tensor, B is a second-order tensor, and C is a second-order tensor
$$\mathbf{A}:\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{C}=[\quad ]:\mathbf{B}$$
$$\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{C}=[\quad ]:\mathbf{B}$$
$$\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{C}=[\quad ]:\mathbf{C}$$
What is the expression in brackets？Can you derive it step by step？thank you very much！

Answer (score 0):

Write the first equation in index notation (employing Einstein summation)
$$\eqalign{
A_{ijkl}:B_{kp}C_{pl} &= \left(A_{ijkl}C^T_{lp}\right):B_{kp} \\
}$$
The term in parentheses is mystery tensor, i.e.
$$T = A\cdot C^T$$
The second and third equations can be written as
$$\eqalign{
B_{ij}C_{jk} &= \left(B_{ij}C_{jk}\;M_{lp}\right):B_{lp} \\
B_{ij}C_{jk} &= \left(B_{ij}C_{jk}\;N_{lp}\right):C_{lp} \\
}$$
So any matrix $M$ which satisfies $M:B=1$ will solve the first equation, i.e. 
$$T=(B\cdot C)\star M$$
where $(\star)$ denotes the dyadic product.

Similarly, any $N$ which satisfies $N:C=1$ solves the second equation, i.e.
$$T=(B\cdot C)\star N$$
Here are some concrete examples. Let $M$ be a matrix in which all of the elements are zero except for $M_{11}=B_{11}^{-1}$. A second solution would take $M_{12}=B_{12}^{-1}$.

Another type of solution takes a random matrix $R$ and scales it to satisfy the constraint
$$M=\frac{R}{R:B}=\frac{R}{{\rm Tr}(RB^T)}
\quad\implies\quad M:B = 1$$
Obviously, there are an infinite number of solutions to the last two equations.